# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[0.0267469, 0.0272395, 0.0268747]'

Tags: python, arrays

I try a code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
test_data='train.csv'
csv_reader = pd.read_csv(test_data)
x_list = csv_reader[['spectra']]
x_list = np.array(x_list)
x = [float(o) for o in x_list[0]]
y_list = csv_reader[['molecule']]
```

and then I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Users/11825/source/repos/deep/shiyishi.py", line 16, in <module>
  x = [float(o) for o in x_list[0]]
File "D:/Users/11825/source/repos/deep/shiyishi.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
  x = [float(o) for o in x_list[0]]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[0.0267469, 0.0272395, 
    0.0268747, 0.0267555]'
```

This is the data's picture:

[image]

How i can save it?

Answer (score 1):

The lists stored in column `spectra` are actually stored as string after you save and load the dataframe.

Try this right after you do `read_csv`:

```
import ast
csv_reader['spectra'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
csv_reader['molecule'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```